# How does naoqi framework address RPC?

Tags: c++, rpc, nao-robot

I'm learning the naoqi framework of nao robot recently. Below is an example of how to access a customized module in its documentation.
(https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/dev/cpp/examples/core/helloworld/example.html#cpp-examples-helloworld)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <alerror/alerror.h>
#include <alcommon/alproxy.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    std::cerr << "Wrong number of arguments!" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Usage: testhelloworld NAO_IP" << std::endl;
    exit(2);
  }

  const std::string robotIP = argv[1];
  int port = 9559;

  try {
    boost::shared_ptr<AL::ALProxy> testProxy
    = boost::shared_ptr<AL::ALProxy>(new AL::ALProxy("HelloWorld", robotIP, port));

    /** Call the sayHello method from the module using its bound name.
    * Since it returns nothing, use the callVoid method.
    */
    testProxy->callVoid("sayHello");

    testProxy->callVoid("sayText", std::string("This is a test."));

    int sentenceLength = testProxy->call<int>("sayTextAndReturnLength",
                         std::string("This is another test"));
    std::cout << "Sentence length is " << sentenceLength << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const AL::ALError& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This code use the "proxy" to call some functions defined in another module. And the module is loaded in a different process. So I think it must deal with the RPC problem. Does anyone know about the underlying mechanism (like CORBA or XML-RPC)? I'm trying to implement the similar mechanism in my own project. Any clue would be fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to register in the [Aldebaran community site](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com) and ask directly in the forums, there you will find the Naoqi developers.

Comment: naoqi is based on SOAP...